# SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]

Tags: tomcat, ssl, configuration, openssl

I use tomcat 8.5 and made a SSL certificate using openssl tool and added it to the Server.

the Server.xml connector configuration is

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/crypto/domain.key"
       SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.home}/crypto/domain.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.home}/crypto/domain.key"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I get the following exception:

```
17-Oct-2017 10:33:58.372 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(J)J
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Pool.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.<clinit>(OpenSSLEngine.java:72)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.getImplementedProtocols(OpenSSLUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:53)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLUtil.<init>(OpenSSLUtil.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation.getSSLUtil(OpenSSLImplementation.java:36)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
```

if I use the Java keytool the Server will run normally but the users will see a security warning telling about insecure certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to port 8080 was used by another task, please close the task then retry.

Comment: The error message refers to port 8443.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the Nio connector:

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

But then you (probably accidentally) include a reliance on Apr:

```
sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
```

Either [follow the instructions to install the Apr library](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html) into your class path, or use the built-in ssl implementation:

```
sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
```

This is still true for Tomcat 10 where Apr has been deprecated.